# Appimage allow access to OS libraries dependencies?

Tags: appimage

Appimage start loading software and dependencies from inside appimage file.
Some softwares have appimage version ( GIMP , Kdenlive , Scribus and etc ) and have support for plugins.
The same softwares being installed using deb files have correct access to plugins and others files paths.

Appimage allow software access to OS paths and libraries dependencies ?
Appimage create an virtual fs where only will be loaded files from Appimage file ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is the question? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 ....
The question is about
Software installed using deb files have access to directory path
In others words
GIMP deb installation is possible install and access plugins in an directory ... 

Appimage is the same way ? Also have acces to any directory to load plugins or even OS libraries dependencies ?